# How to change ggplot2 graphic labels when using aes function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

When plotting with ggplot2 the following piece of code:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=unlist(dataset[5]), y=dataset$x,color = interaction(dataset$Group.3,dataset$Group.4))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(dataset$Group.2 ~ datasetGroup.1)
```

I obtain a boxplot with the following labels:

x :: unlist(dataset[5])

y :: dataset$x

labels :: interaction(dataset$Group.3,dataset$Group.4)))

But i'd like to change it to y :: percentage, labels :: methodology to a personalized label text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `+ labs(x = 'group', y = 'percentage', color = 'methodology')` at the end of your code.

Comment: By the way, you should not use the format `dataset$x` inside `ggplot` - it uses data masking, so you should just use `aes(x=unlist(dataset[5]), y = x, color = interaction(Group.3, Group.4))`, and if possible, use the column name for `dataset[5]`